# two dimensional array checking for similarity

Tags: algorithm

I have the following problem.
I have a two-dimensional arrays `A[Size_1][Size_2]` and I want to throw out elements of the array that are too similar. By too similar I mean that x% of the elements are the same.

I came up with the straightforward but computationally intensive double loop

```
  for(i=0;i<Size_1-1;++i){
    for( j=i+1;j<Size_1;j++){
         counter=0;
        for(p=0;p<Size_2;++p){
            if(A[i][p]=A[j][p]){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter/Size2>=threshold){
            //throwout
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient version ? The array size of A exceeds 10 million so. (Size_1=10 million and Size_2 <=240) 
I would like to have something more efficient.

Comment: Shouldn't `for( j=i ...` be `for( j=i+1 ...` ? You are comparing each row with itself and thus throwing away each row. Also -- what do the elements in the array look like? There might e.g. be optimizations in the case where the elements are `0` and `1`.

Comment: @JohnColeman: j=i was a typo. The rows represent games and the columns represent positions of draughts. The positions are zobrist hashes and there won't be many exact same values in a given row because the games do not include more than 2 fold repetitions. So there will be at most 2 times the same value in any given row. (not accounting for zobrist hash collisions)

Comment: What you are doing now is borderline infeasible. Perhaps you can find a way to partition the space of possible rows into classes in such a way that if two rows are similar then they are in the same (or perhaps adjacent) classes. In one pass through the data, assign each row to a class, and then do something like your current code but only within classes (and neighboring classes).